# Reset or remove the BIOS password on my laptop

Tags: laptop, bios, passwords

I have a laptop but forgot the BIOS password. I cannot go beyond the BIOS password screen and need to continue.

Is there any way I can reset or even remove the BIOS password on my laptop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Plug out all batteries, and the adapter, and remove the RTC battery that supplies power to the CMOS BIOS (according to the service manual p59, it's quite easy).

After about 10 minutes, the BIOS will be reset... along with the password.

To dismantle the dv5, I refer you to the [HP dv5 Hardware and Service Manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01550108.pdf).

[image]

Actual screenshot from the dv5 Hardware Service Manual.

Comment: +1 You really like adding pictures to your answers, don't you? :)

Comment: @alex: what can I say? i'm such a stickler for details. every answer is like a work of art to me. ;)

Comment: A good answer is an answer with a picture, I'm not going to say the opposite, I try to do same on most answers

Comment: @caliban Your answers are always top-notch so you won't hear any complaining from me

Comment: @alex : stop! you are destroying my credibility of being a nasty no-gooder! :)

Comment: @caliban you are a nasty no-gooder, I never said you're not!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a master password, which can be [vendor-specific](http://www.ra2d.com/texts/tips-tricks/bios-masterpassword.aspx) or [laptop-specific](http://dogber1.blogspot.kr/2009/05/table-of-reverse-engineered-bios.html), in which case this [website](http://bios-pw.org/) can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Software**

[IBIOS](http://www.11a.nu/security/pc-bios-security-password-recovery/) - is a PC BIOS toolkit offering password removal/decrypt and BIOS settings modification/backup/restore.

[CmosPwd](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/CmosPwd) - Cmos password recovery
tools 4.8

**Using Hardware Operations** ( from [here](http://www.trap17.com/index.php/Reset-Bios-Guide_t39291.html) )

> On the motherboard there is a small watch battery. Remove this battery along with the power cable from the power supply. Hold down the power button to fully discharge the system. Wait 2-3 minutes then reinstall the battery and plug in your system. Your reset is now complete

(or)

> Some motherboards have a 3 pin jumper by the battery. Lets say that the jumper is on pins 2 and 3. Remove the jumper while the machine is OFF and place onto pins 1 and 2. Power on your machine for a minute. (Note: Your system will not POST). Shutdown your machine and put the jumper back to pins 2 and 3. Your reset is now complete

Answer (score 1):

go to https://www.biosbug.com/ and choose your laptop model then follow the given instructions to remove the BIOS password.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the CMOS battery while the power cable is out and the notebook battery is disconnected.

Some BIOS resets allow you to change a jumper setting, but I've never seen that done on a notebook motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS password should get cleared, if you remove the CMOS battery. For a Laptop the battery placement can be tricky so I'd recommend getting this done by a service engineer if you aren't too comfortable with this.