# Forgot BIOS password, need to reset it

Tags: windows, bios, reset, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reset or remove the BIOS password on my laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/41506/reset-or-remove-the-bios-password-on-my-laptop)

I want to change my BIOS setting but when I press <kbd>F2</kbd> it asks for a password and I've forgotten it.

However, if I press enter it just enters the BIOS but most options are greyed out.

Is there any way to reset the BIOS password?

My BIOS is Intel BX97520J and I can start the system which has Windows Server 2008 installed.

Comment: You need to provide some hardware specific information because this is a hardware specific problem.

Comment: I found your motherboard and included some instructions for resetting the BIOS.  The procedure for clearing the password is different than most consumer-grade boards.  See my answer for more details: http://serverfault.com/questions/91031/forgot-bios-password/91137#91137

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See pages 12-13 of the [user manual for your D975XBX2 motherboard](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/d975xbx2/sb/CS-023492.htm).  The battery is listed as item V in Table 2 on page 12, and the CMOS reset jumper is listed as item S.  The diagram on page 12 should help you locate these on your motherboard.

Pages 52-53 specifically give instructions on clearing your password.  As you may have already noticed, the procedure for clearing your motherboard's password is different from most consumer-grade motherboards.  Here is the summary, but it would be helpful for you to see the diagrams in the user manual:

> **Clearing Passwords**
>
> This procedure
> assumes that the board is installed in
> the computer and the configuration
> jumper block is set to normal mode.
>
> 1. Observe the precautions in "Before You Begin" on page 25.
> 2. Turn off all peripheral devices connected to the computer.  Turn off
>    the computer. Disconnect the computer’s power cord from the AC power source (wall outlet or power adapter).
> 3. Remove the computer cover.
> 4. Find the configuration jumper block (see Figure 30).
> 5. Place the jumper on pins 2-3.
> 6. Replace the cover, plug in the computer, turn on the computer, and
>    allow it to  boot.
> 7. The computer starts the Setup program.  Setup displays the
>    Maintenance menu.
> 8. Use the arrow keys to select Clear Passwords.  Press  and
>    Setup displays pop-up screen
>    requesting that you confirm clearing
>    the password.  Select Yes and press
>    .  Setup displays the
>    maintenance menu again.
> 9. Press  to save the current values and exit Setup.
> 10. Turn off the computer.  Disconnect the computer’s power cord
>     from the AC powe source.
> 11. Remove the computer cover.
> 12. To restore normal operation, place the jumper on pins 1-2.
> 13. Replace the cover, plug in the computer, and turn it on.

Have fun!  :)

Comment: To give a man a fish or teach a man to fish, that is the question :)

Comment: If he's used to consumer-targeted boards or hasn't ever messed around with the insides of a computer, it wouldn't have been obvious that the procedure was more involved than temporarily removing the battery, or briefly shorting pins 2&3 and replacing the jumper on pins 1&2 to reset the BIOS, as is usually the case.  Besides, I've been downvoted before for a lmgtfy link, so I figured I'd play it safe this time.  ;)

Comment: In some cases RTFM in a nicer context should be an acceptable answer as long as a link to TFM is provided.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a BIOS reset jumper or PWD reser jumper on your motherboard, consult the vendor if you can't find it. This also probably belongs on SU.

---

According to your edits that is a desktop motherboard, and it certainly does have a battery on it. It is located between the southbridge heatsink and the 90-degree IDE header. The BIOS reset jumper should be in that location as well. Intel has the manual available on their website too.

Once again though, this belongs on superuser.com

Comment: I tried finding the jumper but could not find it . Is there any way without going to vendor

Comment: The manufacturer of the motherboard is going to have documentation about performing a password reset. You obviously have Internet access, so go find the motherboard docs. It's the right way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

does the motherboard have a battery on it that can be removed? try that!

That used to work back in the day. Remove the motherboard battery, wait a few days to make sure anything storing a charge dis-charges & put the battery back on.  The password is gone & the time needs to be reset.

Comment: There is no battery on mothboard

Comment: what's the model of the motherboard and/or server