# Removing the BIOS password on a Dell Laptop

Tags: laptop, bios, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reset or remove the BIOS password on my laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/41506/reset-or-remove-the-bios-password-on-my-laptop)

I have a Dell D620 laptop. My younger brother set password by mistake on BIOS Setup and forgot it. How do I reset the BIOS Setup program so that password can be reset? Any other alternative is appreciated as well.

Comment: I updated my answer with additional information

Comment: comment by [Kraven:](http://superuser.com/users/32284/kraven) Isn't there any sort of jumper on the laptops motherboard to reset the password?

Comment: comment by [saleemrehman:](http://superuser.com/users/23572/saleemrehman) No, dear kraven. There is not any jumper. I asked laptop repairing shops and they said this is only one way to change BIOS IC. So if you can then do it.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably have to remove the [CMOS battery](http://www.golaptopparts.com/DELL_Latitude_d620-Dell_laptop_CMOS_battery_internal.html) on the motherboard. That will reset the BIOS to factory default and remove the password.

**Update: (since this does not work on this particular model)**
From [WikiAnswers](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_break_BIOS_password_in_Dell_laptop_D620) regarding Dell D620

> There IS a master password unique to
>   your laptop. If you acquired it
>   honestly and are the current owner,
>   you can call Dell and provide them
>   some information (Name, address,
>   phone, serial number, BIOS rev, etc)
>   and they can give you the master
>   password based off of that.
>
> The catch is they'll only do it if
>   it's under warranty. If it's not under
>   warranty, you'll probably have to pay
>   (I think between $75-150 USD).
>
> You can try a BIOS flash utility, such
>   as one that updates your bios, but it
>   usually requires you enter the BIOS
>   password first.

Comment: Though this can be difficult on some laptops.

Comment: Won't work on any laptop with a TPM, though, as the password isn't stored in volatile memory. ThinkPads for example are quite impossible to de-passwordize without replacing the mainboard.

Comment: removing battery procedure doesn't work at all I have already tried it !!

Comment: @Johannes - This is possible one of the stupidest design errors I have heard about.

Comment: @Nifle: You don't set a password if you're likely to forget it. You set it to prevent others of accessing your computer. It's not particularly effective if removing a screw and a battery disables it.

Comment: @Johannes - Not remembering the password should protect the data, not disable the device.

Comment: @Nifle: that's a personal or corporate preference. If the device is disabled, you may have a better chance of recovering a stolen computer.

Comment: @nifle Your correct insofar as there is encryption for drives, and then there is password protection for BIOSes.  Encryption of the drives makes the data inaccessible without the password.  BIOS protection disables the altering of the BIOS without a password, and also prevents the installation of new OS, etc.  One does not affect the other - if data not encrypted, BIOS password will not prevent someone from accessing data by putting hard drive in another computer, for example...

Answer (score 1):

It's a little old but [CmosPwd](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/CmosPwd) might be of help.