# BIOS administrator password reset - Dell laptop

Tags: laptop, passwords, bios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reset or remove the BIOS password on my laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/41506/reset-or-remove-the-bios-password-on-my-laptop)

I forgot the BIOS password for my laptop (Dell). I have to enter the password before my computer boots. What can I do to get access to my laptop again?

Comment: Have you tried the backdoor password "Dell"?

Comment: What model laptop is it?  Some enterprise-class models retain the BIOS password even if you remove the CMOS battery, and you have to follow some extra procedures to clear the password.

Answer (score 1):

Contact Dell Technical Support.  After proving ownership of the machine, they can give you a master password to unlock your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I know some methods.

1. The best and easiest method: Open you computer box, take out the CMOS battery from the mainboard. The BIOS password will be reset to blank.
2. Follow some hard tutorials, it is difficult to do. It is easier if you are a expert. For example this tutorial: [Bypass BIOS Password or Crack CMOS Password](http://passwordreset.org/bios/bypass-bios-password-or-crack-cmos-password.html)?
3. Use the BIOS password recovery tool, but that is not free!

So I would suggest you the first method. I hope it helps.