# Inspirion 5421 admin password

Tags: windows-8

I bought my laptop from at an action and it has a admin password and since I don't know who the original owner is I can't get the help I need from dell so can anyone tell me how to get past the administrative password and reset it

Comment: There are dozens of tools that can reset a Windows user's account I would use one of those

Comment: possible duplicate of [BIOS administrator password reset - Dell laptop](http://superuser.com/questions/159708/bios-administrator-password-reset-dell-laptop), [Reset or remove the BIOS password on my laptop](http://superuser.com/questions/41506/reset-or-remove-the-bios-password-on-my-laptop)

Comment: I assumed it was the "administrator" BIOS password.  @Michael are you talking about the BIOS password, or the Windows Administrator password?

Answer (score 0):

You will need either a recovery disc, or you will need to complete a full format.

There also several "LIVE CDs" out there which can accomplish this.  Try googling it.

Lastly - there are some options available on this [Tutorial for recovering windows](http://www.slideshare.net/windowspasswordunlocker/forgot-windows-81-password-no-reset-disk)

Beyond that, you are unlikely to receive much help here.