# Removing Password from BIOS

Tags: passwords, bios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reset or remove the BIOS password on my laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/41506/reset-or-remove-the-bios-password-on-my-laptop)

I want to reach a computer's BIOS settings, but the BIOS is password protected. I've lost the password.

Is there any way to remove or reset this password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [several](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000235.htm) ways to reset it, but the *easiest* is to **remove the CMOS battery** to reset all settings. If you're not sure what the CMOS battery is, it looks like a larger version of a watch battery, or a button battery. If you post your motherboard specs, we could show you exactly where it is.

Comment: Thanks for your help, really the computer is not mine, I should ask my friend :) BTW I will try to find the CMOS battery myself, but if not I will come and post another comment ;)