# How to get in to the bios when you have a password

Tags: laptop, bios

I was in my bios and saw I could add a password so I did. And now I don't want it as it makes my boot up time longer. How do I delete this password? Or is there even a way to delete it?

Comment: Clearing the CMOS should probably do it.  Check you motherboard manual.  Usually involves removing the coin battery and then moving a jumper.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset or remove the BIOS password on my laptop](http://superuser.com/questions/41506/reset-or-remove-the-bios-password-on-my-laptop)

Comment: You don’t need to resort to clearing the CMOS, *nor should you*. Ignore everybody who says to clear it because that also clears all of the other settings, and if you don’t know how to clear the password, then you probably don’t know what settings you need, and if any of them are not the default, then you could mess up your system (or at least make it or part of it less than optimal). Yes, you can remove just the password. It should be in the same part of the BIOS configuration screen where you entered the password in the first place. If you specify your system model, we can provide details.

Answer (score 0):

what sawdust is saying is. Remove the battery shown here.

[image]

**To do this:** Removing the CMOS battery like the one shown in the picture to the right will cause the system to lose all CMOS settings including the password. To do this locate and remove the CMOS battery on the motherboard for at least five-minutes. After this has been done put the battery back into the computer and turn it back on.

Comment: possible dup: http://superuser.com/questions/41506/reset-or-remove-the-bios-password-on-my-laptop?rq=1

Comment: Where would the battery on my notebook be?

Comment: what kind of laptop?

Comment: I have a Asus K53E.