# Reset Bios Password on Dell Precision T1650

Tags: bios

I need to change the boot order in BIOS on my Dell Precision T1650. I heard that a possibility is to remove the battery from the mother board, but will that make changes to the boot?

[image]

I tried to unlock the bios with bios codes from bios-pw.org, using the system number, but with no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, removing the battery (and either waiting, or changing jumper settings in a way dependent on the motherboard) is the usual way to reset the password.  And yes, it will lose any other CMOS settings you have such as boot priority, power loss settings, date and time, and obscure things to do with RAM and video memory.  However, it's unlikely those are critical and the factory default will usually work fine.

If you don't want to do remove the battery, there is a utility for Windows and GNU/Linux called [CmosPwd](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/CmosPwd)

This question has already been answered here: [Reset or remove the BIOS password on my laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/41506/reset-or-remove-the-bios-password-on-my-laptop).

This looks like a useful resource you may not have tried: http://www.tech-faq.com/reset-bios-password.html

Answer (score 1):

Removing the battery for a while will reset it to the default settings, which are in most cases pretty much what you need.

There might also be a Clear CMOS jumper (refer to manual) which does pretty much the same, but is more reliable
There also might be a dedicated PSWD-Jumper , to clear the password on Dell boards.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the computer and disconnect the power cable from the electrical outlet.

Remove the computer cover.

Locate the 2-pin password connector (PSWD) on the system board.

Remove the 2-pin jumper plug.

Locate the 2-pin CMOS jumper (RTCRST) on the system board.

Move the 2-pin jumper plug from the password jumper to pins into the CMOS jumper.

Plug in AC power to the system and wait ten seconds for the CMOS to clear.

Move the 2-pin jumper plug back to the password jumper.

Replace the computer cover.

Connect your computer and devices to electrical outlets, and turn them on.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Idea about same without removing battery, Simply put wrong password three or four time it will show a code you just write down 
that code and open this [link](https://bios-pw.org/) https://bios-pw.org/ it will ask for "Enter Your Code" Put your code what you have wrote previously, You will get a code from this site. now restart your PC and put code you got from. reset your BIOS. I have tried many times,

**Note: -** It may not works in Some PC, Please don't Mind try in another PC.

Answer (score 0):

You have a blue jumper right next to the white SATA ports on your board. That is for PSWD and right next to it there is a RTCRST jumper as well. Follow the instructions that @Jesse provided and it should work.